# Laravel Blade Nested BelongsTo Relationship access

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-blade

I have a nested BelongsTo relationship in eloquent Laravel, when I try to access it one level its success, but when I try to access it two level. its getting error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Here's my structure models

OrderProduct.php

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product');
}
```

Product.php

```
public function domain()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Domain');
}
```

What I want to do is getting domain information from order_product eloquent, and I did this on blade, but getting error "Trying to get property of non-object"

```
$order_product = OrderProduct::first();
$domain_name = $order_product->product->domain->name;
```

But when I have product eloquent and try to access the domain name, its success

```
$product = Product::first();
$domain_name = $product->domain->name;
```

What should I do to access domain relationship from order_product through product->domain relationship?

Thanks

Comment: You'll get this error if a) `OrderProduct::first()` returns `null` (no record in the database) b) found `$order_product` doesn't have a product connected to it c) found `$order_product->product` doesn't have a domain connected to it d) the `product()` relationship isn't set up properly.

Comment: Share name of local and foreign key both?

Comment: @devk Ok, I think I need to re-check my relationship of the data, is it relation to not connected id or not. Thanks

Comment: What is the result if you `dd($product->domain)`?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occures when you are fetching domain from product which doesn't have domain. You can use laravel optional function:

```
$orderProduct = OrderProduct::with('product.domain')->first();
$domain_name = optional($orderProduct->product->domain)->name;
```

> Note: I also use eager load to reduce queries.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment, this is 1 of the 4 possibilities why this happens. That being said, eager loading, in this case, does not reduce queries at all. It only reduces queries when you're loading multiple parent models